# Check the value of an attribute in magento

Tags: magento

I have a custom attribute yes/no and what i want to do is on the product detail page of my magento site show or hide an image based on wether the value of this attribute is yes or no

my custom attribute is is_real_wood

Comment: If this value is used for every product page and is the same, You shoud try add option to System > Configuration.

After that You can get this value by `Mage::getStoreConfig(XML_PATH)`.

If You still want to have attribute... is this attribute connected with product ? or is it loose attribute that You created in BO ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your attribute was called, say, `show_image` then you read it back like this:

```
<?php if ($_product->getShowImage()) : ?>
    <img .... /><!-- PUT WHATEVER ELSE HTML YOU NEED HERE -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: hi would it not be <?php if ($_product->getshow_image()) : ?>

Comment: Although the magic getter would preserve underscores if you used `getshow_image()` the Magento convention is to use [camel case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase). It is also possible to use `getData('show_image')` but again the camelized version is preferred. In both cases you would miss out any overrides someone had written on the class, should an extension be used that provides an override. That is what coding conventions are for - to improve interoperability.