# Magento How do i add showcase etc label on products in a category

Tags: magento

Hi guys...

know this will appear very novice like to some...but id like to know how i can add SHOWCASE or a stamp with any other name to a product in a category?

The thing is i want to add an image across the product image (preferably in the upper right corner), for a product that i can setup in the backend. The image across will have to be visible in the GRID display and also on the individual product page.

So i basically have TWO questions:-

Qs. Do i have to add a special attribute to the product in the backend for something of this kind to become possible? i guess, it may have to be something similar to NEW FROM this date to that date!!. Any guidance is highly appreciated...

and than Qs2. How do i actually call the across image in both the list.phtml and view.phtml??

I hope this makes sense!!

thanxs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to add a special attribute to the product, you could do it based on the 'Set Product as New from Date' and 'Set Product as New to Date'.  You can do it with a boolean too though, just create an attribute with the Yes/No input type and add it to your default attribute set. Give it an attribute code of showcase.

In your template files (templates/catalog/product/list.phtml and templates/catalog/product/view/media.phtml if you want it on the product view page) you'd add in a piece of conditional code that added in an extra absolutely positioned element to the markup if the product was flagged as being a showcase product,

ie

```
<div class="product-image">

   <?php if($_product->getShowcase()) { ?>
       <div class="showcase"></div>
   <?php } ?>

   <?php 
       $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
       echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
   ?>

</div>
```

and then you'd create css like the following to produce the wee icon in the top corner;

```
.products-grid .product-image { 
    position: relative;
    display: block; 
    width: 244px; 
    height: 156px; 
    margin: 0 0 10px;
 }

.showcase {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 65px;
    height: 66px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
    background: url(../images/showcase.png) no-repeat;
}
```

This is an example I did myself last week, so it uses my image sizes but you get the idea.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Reasons for downvoting appreciated - the answer works perfectly well and answers the OPs question (or my interpretation of it). I understand he's wanting a 'showcase' flag/stamp that displays as extra image in the top corner in product list and view.

Comment: <p>@McNab have created the attribute (attribute code is showcase and not Showcase) and added it to attribute set... am getting a Fatal error call to member function getData on a non object' error</p>

Comment: Hey @Moody.  That could be the problem, using a product attribute you use Camel Case - here's a good thread explaining it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5066012/check-the-value-of-an-attribute-in-magento

Comment: thanxs McNab...my magento backend is not allowing me to name the attribute code starting with a capital letter... therefore, the attribute code is showcase instead of Showcase. Now, as per ur camel case suggestion, it should be called in the same fashion as in ur code above...  <?php if($_product->getShowcase()) { ?>
....but its again giving the error......i dont know... let me check this out again... maybe im missing something :-(

Comment: @Moody - what you've done is correct  (my fault, attribute have to be all lower case - sorry man). Which template are you adding this into?

Comment: @Moody, also - did you set Visible on Product View Page on Front-end
and Used in Product Listing to Yes for your attribute?

Comment: im adding the code within the GRID section of the list.phtml file... and yep...both are set to Yes... only thing different ive done is added the attribute created to new attribute set i have ... but it is applied to the product in question...:-(

Comment: And you've re-indexed and cleared cache?  I don't get it, it's working fine for me in the Grid mode section of list.phtml.  What version of Magento are you using for this?