# How to identify a Magento attribute 'Yes' value in PHP

Tags: php, magento

I'm hoping some kind person can help me please.

I currently have the code below, to identify if today is between the two dates of an attribute in Magento. If they are then a flag is shown on my product. I'd like to know how I could achieve a similar result with a simple yes/no attribute (i.e. if attribute = yes then the flag would be shown).

```
     public function isNew($product)

    {

   return $this->_nowIsBetween($product->getData('news_from_date'), $product->getData('news_to_date'));

    }
```

Comment: Do you need help with creating the attribute?

Comment: Hi, no I have an attribute created but Id like to know how to call on it, if it equals yes. Similar to how the code above does if it's between a date range. Thanks.

Comment: I had to close your question.  You have probably been over-thinking things and missing the obvious answer.

Comment: Hi Clockworkgeek, is there a similar questions that has been asked? Or is there a way it can be re-opened. What is the obvious answer? lol

Comment: Look further up where it says **This question already has an answer here:** [Check the value of an attribute in magento](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5066012/471559)